# Invalid method Exinent_CustomerActivation_Model_Customer

Tags: magento-1.9

Invalid method

`Exinent_CustomerActivation_Model_Customer::sendNewAccountNotificationEmail`

I have use  customer activation extension and  wholesale account form register submitted to  occur this error.

Comment: Can you please mention which extension you used for customer activation??

Comment: wholesale_customer_activation-9.0.2

Comment: I had downloaded this path : https://www.versioneye.com/php/connect20:wholesale_customer_activation/9.0.2

Comment: Now same error other extension used to Invalid method Zestard_Customerattribute_Model_Customer::sendNewAccountNotificationEmail(Array

Comment: I think it is extension conflict problem .please answer for me

Comment: the method not found in that file thats why it gives error